# Como tornar uma imagem normal do post na thumbnail - WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress

É o seguinte:
Estou desenvolvendo um site de acervo fotográfico. Normalmente a imagem que seria mostrada no post seria uma thumbnail, só que como há uma restrição de armazenamento no servidor que irei hospedar o site, preciso pegar as imagens de um drive. Até ai tudo bem. Estou pegando as imagens do One Drive e incorporando ao post como uma mídia normal.

Estou usando um pluguin de busca, que está funcionando normalmente. No entanto queria que os resultados dessa busca fossem mostrados o título e a imagem que estou pegando do drive (em vez de usar a thumbnail), ou seja, eu quero que essa imagem que estou incorporando se torne a thumbnail. Para eu poder exibi-la na busca como se fosse a thumb.

Pesquisei algo sobre isso, mas não encontrei nada. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode transformar essa imagem incorporada no post em "imagem de destaque" dos posts usando o plugin **auto post thumbnail**.

Segundo a descrição:

> Auto post thumbnail is a plugin to generate post thumbnail from first image in post or any custom post type. If the first image doesn’t work it will automatically search for the next one and so on until the post thumbnail is inserted.

Link do plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-post-thumbnail/